# Find file recursively excluding subfolders with specific substring

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I need to get all paths which has a specific file:

```
find apps  -type f -name "project.json"
```

This returns something like

```
apps/sub/frontend-e2e/project.json
apps/sub/frontend/project.json
apps/sub/backend/project.json
```

But I want to exclude all paths with `-e2e` in the last folder.

I tried something like

```
find apps  -type f -name "project.json" -not \( -path "*-e2e" -prune \)
```

Also I need to remove `apps/` and `/project.json` from the beginning and the end of each path. So the result should be:

```
sub/frontend
sub/backend
```

In JS I would do

```
glob.sync('apps/**/project.json', {
    ignore: ['apps/**/*-e2e/project.json']
}).map((path) => {
    // do replacements
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got Bash 4.3 (released in 2014) or later, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob globstar nullglob
for path in apps/**/!(*-e2e)/project.json; do
    p=${path#*/}
    printf '%s\n' "${p%/*}"
done
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` shows such files by default.
  - `extglob` enables "extended globbing" (including patterns like `!(*-e2e)`).  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 because it follows symlinks.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${path#*/}` and `${p%/*}`.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to print the outputs.

Note that this code will not output anything for the path `apps/project.json`.  It's not clear what you would want to output in that case anyway.

Comment: I do get the error `shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`, although the output result is correct...

Comment: It sounds like you've got Bash 3 (e.g. because you are on MacOS).  The `**` is being treated the same as `*` and it works because all of the matches are two levels down.  Run `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to check exactly which version of Bash you've got.

Answer (score 3):

##### Like this:

```
$ tree apps/
apps/
└── sub
    ├── backend
    │   └── project.json
    ├── frontend
    │   └── project.json
    └── frontend-e2e
        └── project.json

4 directories, 3 files

$ find ./apps -not -path '*-e2e/project.json' -name project.json -printf '%h\n'
apps/sub/frontend
apps/sub/backend
```

Comment: Yes, simply `cd apps; then find . -not -path '*-e2e/project.json' -name project.json -printf '%h\n'`